# How do you use Automapper to map navigation properties in EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper

**Note:** I never solved this issue and just moved on to using a straight up Linq query. `.Select(a => new UserDetailsDto { ContactId = a.ContactId, etc`

The issue I'm having is trying to understand how Automapper can be used to map navigation properties with the parent entity all in one query.

Lets say I have a UserDto that closely mirrors the entity and looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InactiveDateTime { get; set; }

    public UserDetail UserDetails { get; set; }
 }
```

Then I have an entity called UserDetail which is mostly made up of navigation properties(I'll post just a few props to keep it short):

```
public partial class UserDetail
{    
    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public int UsertId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int? ProviderId { get; set; }
    public int? FacilityId { get; set; }
    public int? CarrierId { get; set; }
    public int? GenderId { get; set; }
    public int? EthnicityId { get; set; }
}
```

Then its DTO

```
public class UserDetailDto
{
    public int ParticipantDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string Facility { get; set; }
    public string Carrier { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
}
```

I've seen that you can use something like:

```
IEnumerable<UserDto> users = await
      db.DbContext.Set<User>()
           .ProjectTo<UserDto>()
           .ToListAsync();
```

but I don't get how you use that in combination with something like `.ForMember` in the Mapper Config.

I'm just showing what I've seen. I'm totally open to any suggestion on how to accomplish this.

**Edit:**

Mapper Config:

```
config.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
config.CreateMap<UserDto, User>();

config.CreateMap<UserDetail, UserDetailDto>()
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Provider, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Provider.ProviderName))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Facility, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Facility.FacilityName))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Carrier, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Carrier.CarrierName))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Gender, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Gender.GenderText))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Ethnicity, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Ethnicity.EthnicityText))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Orientation, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Orientation.OrientationText))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Education, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Education.EducationText))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Employment, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Employment.EmploymentText))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.EarningRange, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.EarningRange.EarningRangeText))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.Language, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.Language.LanguageCode))
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.CallTimeId, conf => conf.MapFrom(entity => entity.CallTime.CallTimeText));
                    config.CreateMap<ParticipantDetailDto, ParticipantDetail>();

config.CreateMap<UserDetailDto, UserDetail>();
```

Comment: The map User->UserDto is used by ProjectTo to generate an SQL query which will fill your dto-s. See [this](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Flattening.html) for flattening.

Comment: What is your issue? ProjectTo<> will perform the mapping you have defined including `ForMember`, etc.

Comment: @SteveGreene I don't have a `ForMember` setup but my issue is that when I use the `ProjectTo<>` statement I listed above I get a collection of `Users` but `UserDetails` are all null.

Comment: You're going to have to use `Formember` to define nearly every field in the mapping to your DTO, because I'm not seeing a single one that fits the basic conventions that AutoMapper users by default (i.e. none of the property names match between your source and target classes, or the flattening conventions that @LucianBargaoanu mentions above).

Comment: @jmoerdyk see that's where I'm kinda stuck. I know even if my entity and dto have the same property name one will be an `int` and the other a `string`. The issue I'm having is how the heck do I map with that in mind and go from `User`->`UserDetailId`-->`UserDetail`->`ProviderId`-->`Provider`->`ProviderName`

Comment: `.ForMember(d => d.Provider, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.UserDetails.Provider.Name))`  Just a guess since you haven't provided all your classes and/or navigation properties.

Comment: Yeah, show your map code and nav properties. Automapper also has a convention where it would map an entity like `UserDetails.Provider.Name` to a DTO field called UserDetailsDTO.ProviderName without the `ForMember`. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening)

Comment: @SteveGreene Well the nav properties are just `ICollections` generated by EF6 like `public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }`. I posted the `ForMember`s above.

Comment: That looks correct. What is your issue?

Comment: Although your query would need to be from UserDetails, not User in that case: `context.UserDetails.ProjectTo<UserDetailsDTO>().ToListAsync();`

Comment: You may also need to eager load: `context.UserDetails.Include(u => u.Provider).Include(u => u.Facility).{etc}..ProjectTo<UserDetailsDTO>().ToListAsync(‌​);`

Comment: Are you using the static AutoMapper (`Mapper.Initialize()`) or an instance of MapperConfiguration (`config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>)`)?

Comment: Definitely read the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) to prevent extreme performance problems related to *lazy loading/SELECT N+1 problems*.

Comment: @ErikPhilipspublic
`static class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(config =>
            {
`

Yeah I was kinda worried about lazy loading and N+1. That's why I thought it would be best to just ask.